# session id cookie in gwt rpc

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, cookies, session-state

Assuming I'm rolling my own session code, what's the right way to generate a unique and secure session id cookie in java.

Should I not be rolling my own but using something that's already been standardized?

I'm using gwt and the google app-engine platform.

How do I make sessions persist across browser/server restarts?

Comment: You can use session on the Google App Engine. I've provided the link in the updated answer.

Comment: How do I make sessions persist across browser/server restarts?

Comment: One way to have sessions persisted across restarts is to have sessions backed by a file store or database. This is how session failover mechanisms work in most application servers. But I wonder why you have the need for this in Google App Engine.

Comment: Spin-off: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392135/session-persistant-across-browser-server-restart

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Using Servlet Sessions in GWT](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=230)

In the remote service implementation class:

```
String jSessionId=this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getId();
```

In the client code:

```
String jSessionId=Cookies.getCookie("JSESSIONID");
```

[Enabling_Sessions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions)

appengine-web.xml

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't be rolling your own.

The session ID needs to be cryptographically random (not guessable from known sources). It's difficult to get this right yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be relying on the underlying framework's session management features. Servlets & JSPs, Struts and Spring have this support, which you should use.

In the extremely rare case that you are writing your own framework with no underlying session management features to rely on, you could start with the java.security.SecureRandom class to begin with. Of course, don't reinvent the wheel here, for broken session management is the same as broken authentication.

**Update**

Given that you are using Google App Engine, you should rely on the session management features provided by the engine. [It seems that it is not switched on by default](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions).

Comment: Session management is part of J2EE spec and is implemented by app server / servlet container. So unless "writing you own framework" means "writing code on top of raw HTTP protocol" you always have session management to rely on.

Comment: By the way, Axis 1.x does implement session management using the SecureRandom class. I'm not sure on why they chose it, but this is the only one-off case that I have encountered.

Comment: More details on the Axis 1.x session management design can be found at http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/SessionSupport. The supposed reason (that I could think of) for not using HttpSession is to support sessions across different protocols.